# java.io.IOException: Stream Closed ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I keep getting java.io.IOException: Stream Closed and I can't seem to understand why. I create two SensorReadings object (each object is sent an unique string that is used for file names) on a button push (object shown below) that opens two ObjectoutputStreams and writes to two seperate files. This works flawlessly the first time i use it with no exeptions what so ever. When I'm done writing to the files, I press another button that closes the Objectoutputstreams and deletes the files I wrote to.

When I again try to push the button that creates a new SensorReadings object with new Objectoutputstreams and new files with diffrent names, I experience java.io.IOException: Stream Closed everytime i try to write to the file.

Closing the application and restarting it will lead to working flawlessly the first time again, but secound++ time around I get the same error.

code:

```
public class SensorReadings {
    private String macAddress;
    private String cacheFileAccelerationName;
    private String cacheFileEulerAnglesName;
    private File cacheFileAcceleration;
    private File cacheFileEulerAngles;
    private ObjectOutputStream accelerationStreamWriter;
    private ObjectOutputStream euleranglesStreamWriter;

    public SensorReadings(String macAddress, Context context) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormata = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd'-'HH:mm:ss");
        this.macAddress = macAddress;
        cacheFileAccelerationName = dateFormata.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+macAddress+"-acceleration-cache";
        cacheFileEulerAnglesName = dateFormata.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+macAddress+"-eulerangles-cache";

        cacheFileAcceleration = new File(context.getCacheDir(), cacheFileAccelerationName);
        cacheFileEulerAngles = new File(context.getCacheDir(), cacheFileEulerAnglesName);

        try {
            accelerationStreamWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFileAcceleration));
            euleranglesStreamWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFileEulerAngles));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addAccelerationData(AccelerationReading reading){
        try {
            accelerationStreamWriter.writeUnshared(reading);
            accelerationStreamWriter.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addEulerAngleData(EulerAnglesReading reading){
        try {
            euleranglesStreamWriter.writeUnshared(reading);
            euleranglesStreamWriter.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    public void closeFiles(){
        try {
            euleranglesStreamWriter.flush();
            accelerationStreamWriter.flush();
            euleranglesStreamWriter.close();
            accelerationStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cacheFileEulerAngles.delete();
        cacheFileAcceleration.delete();
    }
}
```

Error i get for each time i try to write after creating a new object:

```
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:310)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1946)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1986)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1612)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared(ObjectOutputStream.java:432)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.appitude.appitude.SensorReadings.addAccelerationData(SensorReadings.java:103)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.appitude.appitude.BLE_Connections.lambda$null$31d3e978$1$BLE_Connections(BLE_Connections.java:265)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.appitude.appitude.BLE_Connections$$Lambda$24.apply(Unknown Source)
03-27 21:00:38.526 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.impl.DeviceDataConsumer.call(DeviceDataConsumer.java:51)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.impl.StreamedDataConsumer.lambda$addDataHandler$1$StreamedDataConsumer(StreamedDataConsumer.java:138)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.impl.StreamedDataConsumer$$Lambda$1.onResponseReceived(Unknown Source)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.impl.JseMetaWearBoard.lambda$null$13$JseMetaWearBoard(JseMetaWearBoard.java:699)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.impl.JseMetaWearBoard$$Lambda$30.onChange(Unknown Source)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at com.mbientlab.metawear.android.BtleService$1.onCharacteristicChanged(BtleService.java:188)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:402)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:177)
03-27 21:00:38.527 9882-9894/com.appitude.appitude W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Comment: How and where are you calling addAccelerationData()? You are calling it after you closed the streams.

Comment: This addAccelerationData and addEulerAngleData is called by a callback from a MetaWear Sensor connected by bluetooth thats triggers the call back everytime a new reading is ready and creates a new AccelerationReading or EulerAnglesReading for each reading as parameter to theese functions.

Comment: There has to be something about the ObjectOutputStream writers as I also write to a text file with the data with a PrintWriter that still works flawlessly no matter what. (Haven't included this in the code above as its not part of the problem). But theese PrintWriters are handled about the same way as the ObjectOutputStreams.

Comment: Think I found the problem. I didn't unbind the service connection after streaming data. When connecting the sensors again it received data in the same old callback. Gonne look further into this.

Comment: Your constructor should not catch exceptions. It should let them be thrown to the caller. There's no point in letting the object be constructed in an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The connected bluetooth device that was transmitting data and then written to file, did not stop when the streams were closed and continued trying to use the same streams when activating a new session.